# Legendre Symbol as Trig Product

Tags: number-theory

I was unable to prove these two identities found as exercises in Chapter 5 of Ireland and Rosen. $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}{p}\right)$$ and $$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}3-4\sin^2\left(\frac{2\pi j}{p}\right).$$ Any hints/suggestions on how to approach these would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint for the first one, and hopefully it'll get you started on the second one. (I'm copying by memory from Serre's *Cours d'arithmétique*.)

If $p$ is an odd prime, partition the group $\mathbf F_p^\times$ into $S \cup (-S)$ for some set of representatives under the action of $\pm 1$.

Now let $a\in \mathbf F_p^\times$. For each $s \in S$, we either have $as \in S$ or $as \in (-S)$. In either case we can write $as = \epsilon_s s_a$ in a unique way with $s_a \in S$ and $\epsilon = \pm 1$.

> **Proposition:** We have: $(a/p) = \prod_{s \in S} \epsilon_s$.
>
> *Proof*: Let $P=\prod_{s \in S} s$. We have $$a^{(p-1)/2}P = \prod_{s \in S} as = \prod_{s \in S} \epsilon_a s_a = P \prod_{s \in S} \epsilon_s$$ so $$a^{(p-1)/2} = \prod_{s \in S} \epsilon_s.$$ By
>   Euler's criterion, $(a/p) =  a^{(p-1)/2}$, so $\prod_{s \in S}
>  \epsilon_s = (a/p)$.

Now, can you write $\epsilon_s$ using $\sin$? Hint: $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$.

Comment: What is $\mathbf F_p^\times$? Is it $(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)^\times$? Also, by $S$, you mean $\{1, 2, 3,\ldots, (p-1)/2\}$?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. The answer to you second question is that is one possible choice of $S$. $S$ has to be chosen precisely so $S \cup -S = \bf{F}_p^\times$, which your set $S$ satisfies, but there are others. For example, you could replace $2$ with $p-2$ and leave all the others the same and that is also a proper choice of $S$.

Comment: @IanMateus What Dylan is saying is right. And the $S$ you suggest is particularly important for this problem!